# My Wordpress website is opening too Slow

Tags: php, performance, wordpress, web-hosting

My WordPress website is opening too slow,

I am using woocomerce, flipbook, ajax event calendar , Email newsletter , adrotate , and some other plugin.

Theme Used : Nictitate ( FREE VERSION )

I don't know why it's so slow.

I have installed W3cahce and Cloudflare to attempt to improve the speed of my website but it is still very slow.

Is it a server issue or something else?

Comment: check your error logs if there is any error in plugin that is making site load slower

Comment: yes mohan can you guide me error log path .. ?

Comment: Put the following code in your wp-config.php. This will log all errors, notices, and warnings to a file called debug.log in the wp-content directory. Wordpress doesn't have any default error log. You can also check for the error log of apache.


`define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
@ini_set('display_errors',0);
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);`

Comment: thanks somanth.. will check it

Answer (score 2):

Well there are many factors that as affecting your website performance..

If you are not aware of Google Pagespeed, you can take a look at detailed analysis of your website.

1. You are loading many javascripts on pageload, you can decrease it by implementing something like lazy loading or combining javascripts.
2. Same applies with all the CSS stylesheets, Although they are not blocking rendering, they do consume one request each.
3. You have three images of size 1.2mb each.. which is huge compared to web standards, try reducing them.. Use www.kraken.io like services to optimize images.
4. You have 116 requests which can be reduced..

Detailed analysis on : http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jni.co.in%2F&tab=desktop

Comment: Hey Rahul, can you guide me ? you saying "16 request".. and how i can reduce that ? ...

Comment: You can refer to this : http://www.findurlaptop.com/tech/2013/12/07/how-to-combine-js-and-css-files-with-w3-total-cache-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

This is link [Debugging in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) which should help you debug if there is any issue.

For enabling debugging your code should have:

```
// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

Or you could possibly try this in your wp-config.php

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
@ini_set( 'error_reporting', E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try combining your CSS files to reduce the number of requests. Moreover, you can optimize these CSS files to achieve better performance. [proCSSor](http://tools.maxcdn.com/procssor/) is a useful tool to do that.