# Wordpress websites takes almost a minute to load

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

My wordpress website is very slow. It takes around one minute to load. I tried various plugins and other troubleshooting options to find out the reasons behind high loading time, but I could not find any. The website can be found here
http://www.developmentlogics.com/ 
What can I do to improve the site performance?

Comment: You have a 404 error trying to load an external JS file: http://www.eemt.se/gt/js/4190.js

Comment: try : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25196524/my-wordpress-website-is-opening-too-slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try commenting out the following code from your site to see what happens. There is a timeout error on the loaded JS file 4190.js and it is causing the rest of your website to not complete until that error is triggered.

```
<!--Start of GHRec Script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    var host = ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https://secure.eemt.se" : "http://www.eemt.se");
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + host + "/gt/js/4190.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
})();
</script>
<!--End of GHRec Script-->
```

Comment: I thought the same, but being an intermediate user with no php background, I don't know where to go to remove it. Any idea which wordpress file or plugin is responsible for inserting the code in website pages?

Comment: Without access to your complete site I wouldn't know. This is certainly the culprit. Are you using a ready made theme? What more can you disclose regarding the project?

Comment: I am using a theme called Bivio from whoathemes. Bivio is a parent theme which has been used to create a custom child theme for the website. I tried the string locator plugin and it only showed some redundant file with that code. Removed the code but it is still being inserted in all the website pages.

Comment: It must be an issue with the theme because changing the theme to default wordpress theme solves the issue. I am just unable to find the right way to get rid of that particular snippet being injected in all the pages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for. You can press "f12" and under the networking tab you can see all the timing for the files to be loaded.
[image: network]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my website, though couple of things you need to ensure.
1 - Don't add preloader to a page where you may have a counter. In your website we can see on row with counters, due to which your pre-loader is taking time to load the website.
2. Try to minimize your CSS and compress images on the website.

Comment: I will try to remove the preloader and see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use cache plugin and one thing more add favicon icon to site:

Do these steps :

1) Add cache plugin
2) compress your images, Css and Javascript 
3) delete unwanted images as well as content

Comment: I did all that and it had no effect whatsoever on loading time.